# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - stack around the variable 'osvi' was corrupted on mfc application

Tags: c++, mfc, stack, windowsversion

I've been searching around the internet and I have no idea why this happens, it's not really an obvious array issue.

Here's the function:

```
BOOL IsOsCompatible()
{
    BOOL retVal = 0;
    OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
    GetVersionEx(&osvi);
    if(osvi.dwMajorVersion == 6)
    {
        if(osvi.dwMinorVersion == 0)
        {
            if(SendErrorM("This program has not been tested on Windows Vista(TM).\nAre you sure you want to use it?",MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
                retVal = 1;
        }
        else if(osvi.dwMinorVersion == 1)
        { 
            retVal = 1;
        }
        else if(osvi.dwMinorVersion == 2)
        {
            if(SendErrorM("This program has not been tested on Windows 8(TM).\nAre you sure you want to use it?",MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
                retVal = 1;
        }
    }
    else
        SendErrorM("Your windows verison is incompatible with the minimum requirements of this application.",NULL);

    return retVal;

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `OSVERSIONINFOEX` is larger than an `OSVERSIONINFO`, so

```
    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
```

will write zeroes "outside" (around) `osvi`.

You want

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
```

or (often safer)

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(osvi));
```

Comment: I couldn't agree more on this, the problem appeared when I tried to clean the code a little and changed `OSVERSIONINFOEX` into his smaller brother...

Answer (score 0):

The extra X is your problem:

```
OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
```

Windows A, W and X suck.

**Avoiding Macros**:

```
template <typename T>
inline void zero_memory(T& m) {
    std::memset(&T, 0, sizeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the issue indeed, I thought that they would match, but it seems that the EX one includes some more info resulting in a size mismatch, Thank you very much.